# How to convert the the oracle query to PostgreSQL to get the count of table

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-query

I want to convert the mentioned oracle query to PostgreSQL for getting the count of table

```
select count(*) from student connect by prior std_id=std_roll
```

Comment: Your Oracle query doesn't make sense. A `connect by` **without** a `start with` seems wrong. And _with_ a `start with` it would essentially be the same as `select count(*) from student`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41302331/2235885 exact duplicate by same author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's `connect by` can be re-written as a a recursive [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) in standard SQL (and Postgres):

```
with recursive tree as (
  select std_id, std_roll
  from student
  where std_roll is null --<< I assume you are missing a START WITH in Oracle
  union all
  select c.std_id, c.std_roll
  from student c
    join tree p on p.std_id = c.std_roll
)
select count(*)
from tree;
```

This however does not really make sense. The above is a complicated way of writing `select count(*) from student` (assuming there is a foreign key between `std_roll` and `std_id`)